# Odd result using Oracle trunc()?

Tags: oracle, function, truncate

Why

`select trunc(to_date('23/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DAY') from dual;`

returns

`19.06.17`

instead of expected

`23.06.17`?

We are on Oracle 11.

Comment: `'DAY'` truncates to the start of the week: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8 - but the question is why are you using `trunc()` to start with? `select to_date('23/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;` would already return what you want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `select trunc(END_TIME, 'DD') from KROWA` where KROWA is na alias from `WITH` clouse. When I substitute `trunc()` for `to_date()` I get `date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Comment: @adakozu - you're confusing passing in a date or a string. Your question shows your starting from a string and converting that to a date - with time at midnight - which makes the `trunc()` pointless. If you're really starting from a date variable/column then the trunc makes more sense (but with DD not DAY); but do not pass something that is already a date into `to_date()`. That is **not** what was being suggested. We can only go on what you've told us you're doing - we can't be blamed for offering advice that isn't appropriate for what you're really doing if that is significantly different...

Comment: @AlexPoole I appreciate all the advice. I will keep my statements clearer in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The `DAY` format returns the closest starting day of the week. Depending on your DB configuration, this might be a Sunday, Monday (in your case)...

You probably need the `DD` format instead.

[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084)

Answer (score 1):

`DAY` truncates to closest SUNDAY [[1]](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-trunc/)

you can use `DD`.

```
select trunc(to_date('23/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD') from dual;
```

Comment: It's not always the closest Sunday everywhere in the world and depends on `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter.  Try `ALTER SESSION SET nls_territory='UNITED KINGDOM';` , date output will be a Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong, should be [`DD` format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084):

```
select trunc(to_date('23/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD') from dual;
```

> Date Format Models for the ROUND and TRUNC Date Functions
>
> DDD
>   DD
>   J
>   Day